# PyQGIS to plot multiple axes with different coordinate projection

Tags: pyqgis

I would like to use PyQGIS to batch plot maps with more than one X-axis, with different coordinates.

I have a file with data vertically below a line (geophysics resistivity survey data). The data set is an output from modelling so there are locations at each model cell in a vertical mesh. I would like to plot these data with three X axes, the local distance along the line (xc), the typical UTM easting (xcg) and typical UTM northing (ycg). Elevation is zc.

[image: start of data file]

This image demo.jpg is an example of what I am trying to achieve. The example script below is simplified and only includes a set of points.

[image: Desired outcome]

So far, I have used xc as X and zc as Y and plotted them. Adding a map grid produces this:

[image: output so far]

I have used the following PyQGIS script to generate this (see end).

Is it possible to also have xcg (Easting) and ycg (Northing) on axes as in the example above?

PyQGIS script:

```
import os
#clear the project
QgsProject.instance().clear()
#Set path to files in new project
os.chdir('C:\\1data\\QGISscripting\\multiAxes')

project = QgsProject.instance()

#vectors layer
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("demo.shp", "Demo", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)


#map layout
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName("MyLayout")
manager.addLayout(layout)
pc = layout.pageCollection()
pc.pages()[0].setPageSize('A5', QgsLayoutItemPage.Orientation.Landscape)
project.layoutManager().addLayout(layout)

#Map
map=QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
map.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(190,60, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map.setFrameEnabled(True)
map.zoomToExtent(iface.mapCanvas().extent())

# Set map item position and size (by default, it is a 0 width/0 height item placed at 0,0)
map.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(150,350,QgsUnitTypes.LayoutPixels))
layout.addLayoutItem(map)

#grid
map_grid=QgsLayoutItemMapGrid("Grid", map)
map_grid.setEnabled(True)
map_grid.setIntervalX(50)
map_grid.setIntervalY(10)
map_grid.setAnnotationEnabled(True)
map_grid.setAnnotationPrecision(0)
map_grid.setAnnotationDirection(1, 0)
map_grid.setAnnotationDirection(1, 1)
map.grids().addGrid(map_grid)
layout.addLayoutItem(map)


exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToImage("out.png", QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())
#exporter.exportToPdf("newmap.pdf", QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())

print('Done!')
```

Answer (score 0):

These seem to be cross sections rather than maps. Seismic Unix might be a better tool for batch plotting them. It’s at cwp.mines.edu

If not, then your use of the three horizontal axes seems redundant. It is common, when showing linear survey data, to show a map with lines such as A-A’, B-B’, etc. Then show the cross sections for each line with just the Distance axis, ie, leave out Easting and Northing, as they appear to be redundant. Distance by convention goes from A to A’.

This allows for dog-leg lines, as the distance is parametric, not a distance from the start of the line (unless the line has only two points).